# Effect of moving a method from public to private

Tags: c++

I was doing some code cleanup, and started wondering about a certain something.

Assuming that I have a program that compiles, runs, and generally does what it's supposed to.

Now I move a certain class member method from public to private (or protected), and the code still compiles without an error.
Is it theoretically possible to have such a scenario where the behavior of the program would change as a result of the code change?
If so, I would love to see an example.

Comment: If your public method was only being called by the class that owns it, there would be no change.  If something else that didn't have friend access was calling it when it was public and you changed it to private, it would no longer have access and would then not compile.

Comment: Yes, but that does not fit the question.  I stated it still compiles after the change.

Comment: @zero298 It isn't the compile-time problem's the OP's is referring to. They want to know if it *still compiles* could there be any adverse effects that are not immediately apparent. I.e., could the move trigger alternate behavior even though it still compiles.

Comment: Right now i can't think of an example that actually "works", but i think you might be able to construct something where the now-private method gets "replaced" by a method in a superclass, which would change your program. Or maybe some multiple inheritance thing substituting a different method.

Comment: @hatchet:  My magic skills are low.  Can you create an example?

Comment: @hatchet: That code is C#.  I don't see how this is relevant to C++

Comment: @Photon - missed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access specifier of a method explicitly does not affect lookup (it's instead checked after the lookup is completed) so I don't believe there could be any hidden changes in functionality in the absence of undefined behavior (for example you have another version of the class where the function is still public).

Comment: So you're saying that given well behaved programs, it's not possible to construct such an example?

Comment: If you have a `public method(int x)` and a `public method (char x)`, and make the 2nd one private, will `method('0')` call the int version of the method or give a compiler error?

Comment: @Guntram Blohm: Checked that.  It would fail compilation after the change

Answer (score 0):

Access control is checked after lookup to ensure what you suggest does not alter the program's behavior. Just remember that reordering member variables, even private ones, may alter behavior as they are constructed in the order they appear in the class declaration.